# Downloading and finally executing Flask to make it work or connecting to the web

Tags: flask

It appears that the program is already installed in Pycharm. I even created a blog about how to do it with pictures.
Nonetheless, it has been a nightmare getting to execute and finally connect on the web.

What code am I missing, I did it all thru Pycharm.

Comment: We cannot see the blog post. And please details here what is your problem.

Comment: I can't seem to install Flask with PyCharm community IDE. Apparently I followed all commands to install Flask in PyCharm. But it never opens or visibly accesible. Somebody said that I must pay Pycharm Pro in order to easily open Flask. Is there any other way to access, open, Flask besides using Pycharm IDE? Thank you.

Comment: There are multiple ways to run Flask. [Flask - Quickstart](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/), depending on your OS. The one advised in the documentation is to use the flask command in a terminal or `python -m flask` that does the same. You can create a configuration in PyCharm to run this command.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, in order to Install Flask to do web apps. You must pay Pycharm Pro. This is true if you have a windows laptop or desktop. I am not certain about other programs where you can do Python web apps for free. But I will research that.

Comment: Why would you want to pay? normal pip install works and flask is available for free